# Read and update a custom field in woocommerce_product_on_backorder hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have a custom field in Woocommerce variation products and I try to update that field wherever there is a backorder. This is the code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder', 'reduce_second_stock' );
function reduce_second_stock( $array ){
    $temp = get_post_meta($array['product']->ID, 'second_stock', true);
    update_post_meta( $array['product']->ID, 'second_stock', $temp - $array['quantity'] );
}
```

The custom field is called `second_stock` which is just a number. What I try to do is to reduce that number based on the backorder quantity of that order.

However, even if the regular stock of the product is updated, my custom field stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_reduce_stock_levels.html#116), `$array['product']` is the `WC_Product` Object, so to get the product Id you need to use the related method `get_id()`…  Since WooCommerce 3 and [CRUD Objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0), you can use directly the `WC_Data` methods `get_meta()`, `update_meta_data()` and `save()` on the `WC_Product` Object like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder', 'reduce_second_stock' );
function reduce_second_stock( $array ){
    if( $original_stock = $array['product']->get_meta('second_stock') ) {
        $array['product']->update_meta_data( 'second_stock', ( $original_stock - $array['quantity'] ) );
        $array['product']->save();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Awesome. Now it is triggered! However, I have another problem. If my stock has 5 items and I order 6, I expect that only 1 will be removed from the second stock custom field. However, the action above removes all 6 of them. Any workaround?

Comment: @Tasos Sorry my answer here is just making your custom field allowed to be read and updated in the hooked function. For this other problem, you should ask a new question please.